# Defining Array Values

Tags: php, arrays

Here is my array;

```
$date = array('16-01-14','16-01-28','16-02-14','16-02-28','16-03-14','16-03-28',
    '16-04-14','16-04-28','16-05-14','16-05-28','16-06-14','16-06-28','16-07-14',
    '16-07-28','16-08-14','16-08-28','16-09-14','16-09-28','16-10-14','16-10-28',
    '16-11-14','16-11-28','16-12-14','16-12-28');
```

What I'm trying to achieve is create a `foreach` statement that creates a similar output to the picture below.

**Picture Example**

[image]

**Example**

So for each line in the example the `start_date` and `end_date` are defined as variable which I can refer back to. The pattern goes like;

01
12
23
34
45...

What I'm basically trying to achieve is perform an action on each one of the lines in the picture using both the `start date` and `end date` and have the action repeated for each line in the picture.

Comment: Every odd array index is the start date and every even one is the end date?

Edit: I misread. Every end date is the next start date?

Comment: @Jaime yes that is correct every end_date is the next start_date

Comment: Have you tried writing a `foreach()` statement for this yet?

Comment: @JayBlanchard I have tried however nothing close to what I'm trying to achieve as I'm new to using arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate through the array, and echo each value into the start date and the next value as the end date. Note that you will need logic for the last start date - is it the second to last array value? if so - you will need to reduce the count by 1.

```
$date = array('16-01-14','16-01-28','16-02-14','16-02-28','16-03-14','16-03-28',
  '16-04-14','16-04-28','16-05-14','16-05-28','16-06-14','16-06-28','16-07-14',
  '16-07-28','16-08-14','16-08-28','16-09-14','16-09-28','16-10-14','16-10-28',
    '16-11-14','16-11-28','16-12-14','16-12-28');

echo "<table>";

for($i=0;$i<count($date)-1;$i++){
   $x=$i+1;
   echo"<tr><td>".$date[$i]."</td><td>".$date[$x]."</td></tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
```

and this was the outcome:

```
Start Date  End Date
16-01-14    16-01-28
16-01-28    16-02-14
16-02-14    16-02-28
16-02-28    16-03-14
16-03-14    16-03-28
16-03-28    16-04-14
16-04-14    16-04-28
16-04-28    16-05-14
16-05-14    16-05-28
16-05-28    16-06-14
16-06-14    16-06-28
16-06-28    16-07-14
16-07-14    16-07-28
16-07-28    16-08-14
16-08-14    16-08-28
16-08-28    16-09-14
16-09-14    16-09-28
16-09-28    16-10-14
16-10-14    16-10-28
16-10-28    16-11-14
16-11-14    16-11-28
16-11-28    16-12-14
16-12-14    16-12-28
```

Comment: @gavgriff Thankyou Very much exactly what I was after really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

The solution using `array_slice` and `implode` functions:

```
$i = 0;
$size = count($date);
echo "start_date | end_date" . PHP_EOL;
while ($i < $size) {
    if (isset($date[$i + 1])) {
        echo " " . implode(" : ", array_slice($date, $i, 2)) . PHP_EOL;
    }    
    $i++;
}
```

The output:

```
start_date | end_date
 16-01-14 : 16-01-28
 16-01-28 : 16-02-14
 16-02-14 : 16-02-28
 16-02-28 : 16-03-14
 16-03-14 : 16-03-28
 16-03-28 : 16-04-14
 16-04-14 : 16-04-28
 16-04-28 : 16-05-14
 16-05-14 : 16-05-28
 16-05-28 : 16-06-14
 16-06-14 : 16-06-28
 16-06-28 : 16-07-14
 16-07-14 : 16-07-28
 16-07-28 : 16-08-14
 16-08-14 : 16-08-28
 16-08-28 : 16-09-14
 16-09-14 : 16-09-28
 16-09-28 : 16-10-14
 16-10-14 : 16-10-28
 16-10-28 : 16-11-14
 16-11-14 : 16-11-28
 16-11-28 : 16-12-14
 16-12-14 : 16-12-28
```

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to use `foreach`, you can shift the first array element (the initial start date) off before the loop. Then as you loop, first use the current element as the end date, then set it as the start date for the next iteration (row).

```
$start_date = array_shift($date); // get the initial start date (and remove it from $date)

echo '<table>';
foreach ($date as $end_date) {
    echo "<tr><td>$start_date</td><td>$end_date</td></tr>";
    $start_date = $end_date;   // end date becomes next row's start date
}
echo '</table>';
```